# is it possible drupal like taxonomy and user managment in joomla?

Tags: drupal, joomla, user-management, drupal-taxonomy

is it possible in joomla to make pages and users like drupal?

in drupal there is an option called taxonomy by which we can create tags which are similar into a group and can create user groups who can use a particular group of tags. and those group of users can manage pages created under those taxonomy group.

i want to do as follows

1) create pages and sub pages

2) create user groups, Users in Group X can manage(add, edit, delete) some pages and their related sub pages and cannot access other pages for managing (can view).

the above is possible in drupal, is it can be achieved in joomla also?

in joomla we can create articles and can give them as pages of website by attaching to a menu item.

Can a user in joomla can manage a menu and menu item ?

Sorry if i confuse, please ask if any clarification required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using K2 and something like JUGA. You can create you categories/articles with custom structure and then set permissions using JUGA. Not quite as seamless as Drupal, but might be enough for you.

Alternatively, you could try using the 1.6 Beta (not for production use), which has the proper ACL implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should be able to accomplish what you want using just K2. K2 has the ability to create user groups that are then assigned to specific K2 categories. Using that along with the front end editing features will allow you to control who can submit new content as well as whether the content is automatically published or not.